# What is the process for changing the "lead owner" through the salesforce API?

Tags: automation, salesforce, zapier, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

Currently creating an automation using zapier which should change the lead owner in salesforce when the event takes place. It successfully reaches salesforce but does not actually change the "lead owner" but it is instead reflected in the lead history section. There is no clear salesforce workflow or rule in place which should prevent this automation from occurring.
[image: Update lead zap (Owner refers to lead owner)]

[image: Lead history salesforce]

When the automation executes as you can see above, the lead owner successfully changes in the lead history but it does not actually change the lead owner of the actual lead so we are manually having to go back and change this.

**Has anybody else faced similar issues when working with the salesforce API when changing the lead owner and if so what was the solution**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this, just broke down the issue and resolved by doing the following (This was beyond the standard salesforce scope of support as we use custom prefill URL's for anybody wondering):

1. Create a new hidden field called something such as 'tmp_owner'
2. Assign the new lead owner ID to a new text field called 'tmp_owner' which is hidden on
   the lead field to other salesforce org users
3. Added a salesforce workflow rule when this 'tmp_owner' is populated replace the 'lead owner' field with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Lead assignment rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_leadrules.htm&type=5). It's separate area in Setup, different from workflows, flows, process builder and triggers.

You probably have an active rule that runs on update, not only on insert. Your API call works OK, changes the OwnerId field but then the assignment rule overwrites that. That's why you see it as 2 entries in history.

You can also confirm what's going on byenabling debug logging on the integration user and check if it captures anything.

Optionally you could also suppress the assignment rule during the update. This is... questionable. I mean talk with your SF admin first, if you suppress the rule then you moved bit of logic out of salesforce. 2 months later nobody will remember why something doesn't fire, it's cleaner to just modify the rule to skip these records.

If Zapier uses SF REST API there's a HTTP header it should send, [`Sforce-Auto-Assign: FALSE`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_autoassign.htm). If it uses SOAP API - similar thing will have to be set in the SOAP message's header, check the WSDL for exact syntax?